# Python typing "\"

Tags: python, string

I want to print a string that ends with the \ character, but the problem is it makes the following ") part of the string, so won't work. Is there any way to end a string with \ being considered a regular character?

```
print("somestuffhere\") and this is still part of that string...
```

Comment: This can solve it: `\\")`

Answer (score 1):

Put another "\" character behind it. This escapes the escape character. Like so:

```
print("somestuffhere\\")
```

Comment: @reemer9997 You should really look things like this up yourself though. This is a problem that everyone experiences when they first use an escape character in a string, making it very easy to research yourself. Keep that in mind when asking questions in future. :)